# Rational approximation of an integer combination of two irrationals

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $x$ be an irrational number, and $\beta$ strictly larger than its irrationality index, which means that for some $C>0$, for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^*$, 
$$d(nx,\mathbb{Z})>C n^{-\beta}.$$
It is known that for a.e. irrational number $x$, the irrationality index is $1$.
It is even known that some numbers satisf the above  for $\beta=1$ (for instance, $x=\sqrt{2}$).

By arguments from measure theory, I have been able to prove that if $a_n$ satisfies $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n<\infty,$$ almost every couple $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies for some $C>0$ $$d(nx+my,\mathbb{Z})>Ca_{|n|+|m|},n,m\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Ideally, I would like, as for a single number $x$, find irrational numbers $(x,y)$ such that this holds in the limiting case $a_n=n^{-2}$.

Has anyone an idea? Or has anyone a useful reference for such things?

Comment: I suspect the answer is no. Almost all real numbers $x$ have irrationality index $2$, and it seems very likely that one can a sum of two such numbers which is a Liouville number, for example.

Comment: E.g., if $\alpha$ is Liouville, then chances are that $\alpha+\sqrt2$ and $\alpha-\sqrt2$ are both index $2$ while their sum is $2\alpha$.

Comment: Ok thanks. So it is likely that even if I carefully choose $x$ and $y$, there will be no better bound than $0$?

Comment: I completely modified the question as I have made some progress on my side.

Comment: We must assume $(m,n) \neq (0,0)$, else $d(nx+my, {\bf Z}) = 0$ . . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, such $(x,y)$ exist; for example,
$x = \root 3 \of 2$ and $y = x^2$.
For $l,m,n \in \bf Z$, define
$$
N(l,m,n) := l^3 + 2m^3 + 4n^3 - 6lmn \in {\bf Z};
$$
this is the algebraic norm 
$$ 
 (l + mx + nx^2)
 (l + m\rho x + n \bar\rho x^2)
 (l + m\bar\rho x + n \rho x^2)
$$
of $l + mx + nx^2$,
where $\rho$ is the cube root of unity $e^{2\pi i/3} = (-1 + \sqrt{-3})/2$.
But if $(m,n) \neq (0,0)$ then
$l + mx + nx^2 \neq 0$, so $\left|N(l,m,n)\right| \geq 1$ and
$\left|l + mx + nx^2\right| \gg (|l|+|m|+|n|)^{-2}$.
Taking for $l$ the integer nearest to $-(mx+nx^2)$ we deduce that
$d(mx+nx^2,{\bf Z}) \gg (|m|+|n|)^{-2}$, as claimed.

The same argument (which generalizes the familiar one for $\sqrt 2$)
shows that in general if $x$ is an algebraic number of degree $D$ then
$$
d\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{D-1} n_j x^j, {\bf Z}\Bigr) \gg
 \left( \sum_{j=1}^{D-1} \left| n_j \right| \right)^{1-D}
$$
for $n_1,\ldots,n_{D-1} \in \bf Z$ not all zero.
This is best possible up to the value of the implicit constant, because
Dirichlet's celebrated "pigeonhole" argument shows that conversely
for any $N$ one can find integers $n_1,\ldots,n_{D-1} \in [-N,N]$, not all zero,
such that $d(\sum_{j=1}^{D-1} n_j x^j, {\bf Z}) \ll N^{1-D}$.

Comment: Sorry I did not provide a reference; none of this is new,
but it's easier to recall the proofs than to find them in the literature.

Comment: I see, pretty neat, thanks! "Not new" but for me it is dropped from the sky... Do you know f by any chance such arguments extend even further to infinite sums? i.e. I'm looking for $x_j$ such that for integers $n_j$, the distance from  $\sum_j x_j n_j$  to $\mathbb{Z}$ is bounded from below by the inverse value of some norm of $\|(n_j)\|$ on the space of integer sequences...

Comment: Experiments suggest that if $C=.1322$ then $d(mx+nx^2,{\bf Z}) > C (|m|+|n|)^{-2}$.  Any thoughts on a provable and/or more precise value of $C$?

Comment: Seems the best $C$ is $1/(6x) = 0.13228342\ldots$.
For large $k$, if $l+mx+nx^2 = (x-1)^k$ then its product with $(|m|+|n|)^2$
depends on the phase of $(e^{2\pi i/3}x - 1)^k$, which can be made arbitrarily
close to the optimum. As with $\sqrt2$ for $d(nx,{\bf Z})$, the choice
$x = \root3\of 2$ here is the most familiar but not quite the best;
taking for $x$ the real root of $x^3-x+1$, or the root $2\cos(2\pi/7)$ of
$x^3+x^2-2x-1$, should yield somewhat larger $C$.  To be sure the exact
value of $C$ is partly an artifact of the choice of quadratic factor: [cont'd]

Comment: changing $(|m|+|n|)^2$ to say $m^2+n^2$ or $\max(|m|,|n|)^2$ would change
both the liminf and (probably) the sequence of algebraic units that attain it.
But the liminf would remain finite and positive.

Comment: Very cool.  Thank you.  For $x = \root 3 \of 2$  I could only get down to .132283780 before running out of patience.  Two more digits and an ISC lookup and I may have got there.

Comment: When $x = \root 3 \of 2$ and the quadratic factor is $\max(|m|,|n|)^2$ , I get a minimum value near 0.0545802011.  With the quadratic factor $m^2+n^2$ it may be that the minimum occurs when $(l,m,n)=(19,-5,-8)$ although I would not bet the farm on it.